# Event management: Using JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jlayeredpane

I am developing a RTS game in java. In my main game Panel, I want to have multiple layers on each other. One layer for showing the game board and multiple ones as control panels which are set on the game board layer. Something like the main frame in Dota or StrongHold.

What is the best way to handle the events while having multiple layers? and furthermore, is it a good way after all to use JLayeredPane for putting a frame on the game board or there is a better way?

Comment: Sorry, what I'm "trying" to ask is, what do mean by "events while having multiple layers"? :P

Comment: I mean that these is a layer on which you can see heroes and units moving, and there is another layer on the top of it as a control panel (which contains small map, details, control buttons, etc). And my problem is that just the top layer listens to events and other layers don't.

Comment: Could have it so that each upper layer only covers as much of the lower layer as needed, that is, the units would be small square elements which would only cover a very small section of the board (below them).  The controls would cover a larger area, but because they are self contained, would not affect anything they don't cover...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Assume we have layer A and layer B. You mean if we have A on the top B in Z-ordering, can events be triggered for the components of A which can been seen?

Comment: Yes, A (been on top) will block mouse events from getting to B where A covers B (assuming A has registered a `MouseListener`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55955/discussion-between-melika-barzegaran-hosseini-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: @MadProgrammer And another question. What if the component is transparent while covering a component which has a listener? I want to put a designed frame around my small map. how can I handle that? I would be really thankful for sharing you experiences in such cases. :)